# Check if data is in array in PHP

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter 3 I need to compare two json object.
To explain better, below the json data I have to check:

```
[
    {
        "id":23456,
        "name":"Some data"
    },
    {
        "id":98765,
        "name":"Other data"
    },
    {
        "id":12345,
        "name":"A glider"
    },
    {
        "id":34567,
        "name":"Other aircraft"
    }
]
```

I need to compare the above data with the following json object.

```
[
    {
        "id":23456,
        "name":"Some data",
        "available": 0,
    },
    {
        "id":98765,
        "name":"Other data",
        "available": 1,
    },
    {
        "id":12345,
        "name":"A glider",
        "available": 0,
    },
    {
        "id":34567,
        "name":"Other aircraft",
        "available": 0,
    },
    {
        "id":56789,
        "name":"Dummy aircraft",
        "available": 0,
    },
]
```

I have to select data from the first json object that compare in the secon one with "available" field equal to 1.

Hope the edited my question, I hope is now clear.
My apologize for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$data = json_decode('[
    {
        "id":23456,
        "name":"Some data"
    },
    {
        "id":98765,
        "name":"Other data"
    },
    {
        "id":12345,
        "name":"A glider"
    },
    {
        "id":34567,
        "name":"Other aircraft"
    }
]');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
     if (property_exists($data[$i], 'id') && property_exists($data[$i], 'name')){
         $data[$i]->available = 1 ;
     }else{
         $data[$i]->available = 0;
     }
}
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback and help Nero. If I'm not wrong...the code above parse the first JSON data and add the available flag...but doesn't compare the first JSON data with second one. What I have to do is...take each data in the first JSON object...check if it's in the second JSON structure, return it if in the second JSON structure its available flag is 1. Again thanks.